# Multiple Conditions In Excel

Tags: multiple-conditions

I entered the below formula into excel.  When I copy the formula down for the rest of my sheet, it gives the "eligible" value to all fields even when the J field has no data to pull from.  What am I missing?

=IF(J3<=40,"Eligible",IF(AND(J3<=30, J3>=39.99), "Particially","No"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank is interpreted as zero, so J<=40 will be true. You probably need to put an IsNumber check in there too.

=IF(AND(J3<=40,ISNUMBER(J3)),"Eligible",....

EDIT: based on your comment, you can simplify this by reversing the logic, and you don't need an and clause.

=IF(J1<30,"no",IF(J1<40,"partial","eligible"))

Comment: That worked for blank fields, but it is still saying "eligible" for a field that would fall into the second condition and should be "particially".

Comment: What is in that cell?

Comment: I created a cell that equals 31.2 and one that equals 5 and they still populate as "eligible".

Comment: Can we see the updated formula? Both 31.2 and 5 are less than 40, which was the condition in your original post for "eligible".

Comment: What should my formula be if I want the field to populate with "eligible" if the number is 40 and above, "particially" if the number falls in the range of 30-39.99, and "no" if the number is less than 30?

Comment: @user3494361 I have updated my answer, which will work with the conditions you have stated. I will leave it to you to deal with IsNumber checks.

Comment: That still isn't working. Now I am getting a "You've entered too many arguments for this function message."

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer :-) I have checked in both open office and excel, and the formula works.

Answer (score 0):

I think logic is wrong.
Try this (included remark by John Barça):

=IF(ISNUMBER(J3),IF(J3<30,"Eligible",IF(AND(3<=39.99,J3=30),"Partially","no")),"Not a number")

Or please describe what you want to get.